# I want to replace a character with a specific number, what formula do I input to do this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find, replacement

So for instance if I put in the letter 'W' I would like the cell to automatically replace with the number 4,000 and if I put in the letter 'B' I'd like the cell to replace with the number 3,000. If I then change the letter I'd like the cell to automatically change to the new number.

Comment: if the cell has a formula, and you over type it with a value, you will lose the formula. You need VBA for something like this. Google VBA and CASE or change event.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have googled this but I'm not really sure what it means, it says I need to open a code window to input the VBA event and I don't know what a code window is or where to find one.

Comment: Take a look at the late Chip Pearson's web site article on  [Events and Event Procedures](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Events.aspx)

Comment: @user1198267,, this you want only in ONE CELL or in a Column like if A1 is W then B1=4000 and so others or may be if A1 is W then A1=4000 !

Comment: I'd like it to be the case that an entire column can be formatted so that if I enter the value 'W' for instance in any of the cells in that column then it will convert to the relevant number. I could put 'W' in A1 for example and it would change the value to 1,000 and then I could put 'B' in B1 and it would change to 4,000. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try this code:*

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

If Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then   

If Target.Value = "W" Then
Target.Value = 4000

ElseIf Target.Value = "X" Then
Target.Value = 5000

ElseIf Target.Value = "Y" Then
Target.Value = 6000

End If
Endif

End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- Either press **A**lt+F11.
- Or **R**ight click the Sheet TAB, then from Pop up menu hit **V**iew code.

*You will get VBA editor's window.*

- **C**opy & **P**aste this code.
- Press **C**trl+s to Save.
- Now press **A**lt+Q to return to the Sheet.
- Now as soon you enter either W, X or Z in column A, this code with replace it with the assigned number.

**N.B.**

- You may add more conditions.
- Alphabets and respected numbers are editable.
- You may adjust the Column using the code line,,

`If Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then`

*Here 1 represents any one column.*

It should be also,,

```
If Target.Columns.Count >= 1 And Target.Columns.Count <= 5 Then
```

---

*If you want to works only in Column A then better use this code.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub


If Target.Value = "W" Then
Target.Value = 4000


ElseIf Target.Value = "X" Then
Target.Value = 5000

ElseIf Target.Value = "Y" Then
Target.Value = 6000

End If
End If


End Sub
```

---

**N.B.**

- This, `Me.Range("A:A"))` is editable and should `Me.Range("A:C"))` or   `Me.Range("A1:A100"))` also.
- Save the Workbook as **M**acro Enable ( .xlsm ).

Comment: Glad to help you @user1198267 ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: +1 Very Nice Rajesh, I will be using aspects of this for a report I'm currently building, may need some further tweaks so may ask a new question on here

Comment: Glad to hear from you @PeterH ,, yes U may ask without any hesitation,, also just pass me the question's link so that I can immediately catch it,,, ☺